# Zend Framework setup issue

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, include-path

Trying to setup Zend Framework as instructed in [this manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html)

```
$paths = array(
    realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/libs/Zend'),
    '.',
);
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
```

Gives fatal error. (My local webserver is IIS. Remote one is linux)

Local:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' (include_path='D:\Web Server\tural.us\core\serverside\libs\Zend;.') in D:\Web Server\tural.us\core\content\pages\utube.php on line 2
```

Remote:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' (include_path='/home/tural/public_html/core/serverside/libs/Zend:.') in /home/tural/public_html/core/content/pages/utube.php on line 2
```

But in fact, I see that the path in error message is totally right : `D:\Web Server\tural.us\core\serverside\libs\Zend;`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove Zend from the path...

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/libs/')
```

Zend looks for Zend/etc whenever it loads stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I think your inclusion of /Zend in the include path is causing the problem. Try:

```
$paths = array(
    realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/libs'),
    '.',
);
```